# Why proftpd allows only downloading and not uploading

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, virtualbox, bitnami, proftpd

Why proftpd allows me only downloading and not uploading?

I installed proftpd at Lbunto (in virtualbox guest system) via Bitnami XAMPP.
XAMPP automatically installed proftpd at first time (and Apache, PHP, MySql).

Via proftpd i could download all the files from the htdocs to my host (Windows 10).
But if i try uploading files i got this error from FileZilla-Client:

```
Start uploading from \ Recording-6.trec
Command: CWD /
Answer: 250 CWD command successful
Command: TYPE I
Answer: 200 Type set to I
Command: PASV
Answer: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,178,25,166,193).
Command: STOR recording-6.trec
Answer: 550 recording 6.trec: Permission denied
```

I found no restrictions in the config file

```
/opt/lampp/etc/proftpd.conf
```

There I also find the FTP login data.
I also found the same data via

```
sudo/opt/lampp/lampp security
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks this could be a problem with the permissions of the proftpd user and the directory you are trying to upload to.
  Could you check this or provide detailed steps of your procedure ?

Thanks.

Comment: and i want recomand using vsftpd. later i installed all new with vsftpd. and it was easier for me. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04